# Centering my O3D canvas

Tags: canvas, o3d

I would like to have a centered O3D canvas.  Can anyone suggest how I might do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing:

```
<div id="o3d" style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"></div>
```

You write:

```
<div id="o3d" style="width: 600px; height: 600px; margin:0 auto;"></div>
```

O3D inserts itself into the div's that have id's starting with "o3d". Any styling that you apply to the div, is essentially applied to the O3D object. `margin:0 auto;` just means that you want 0 vertical margin and you want balanced horizontal margin.